# How do I define a `typing.Union` dynamically?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, dynamic-typing

I am using [Typeguard](http://typeguard.readthedocs.io) in a couple if projects for type checking at run time in Python. It works pretty well.

I have encountered a situation where the type of a function parameter is a `typing.Union` made up of a few dynamically collected data types. E.g.

```py
def find_datatypes():
    # some stuff ...
    return (str, int) # dynamically generated list / tuple

datatypes = find_datatypes()
```

Now I want to generate a `typing.Union` from `datatypes` for eventual use in a function. I expected unpacking syntax to work:

```py
my_union = typing.Union[*datatypes]

@typeguard.typechecked
def some_function(param: my_union):
    pass
```

However, it did not:

```py
    my_union = typing.Union[*datatypes]
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How would I achieve what I want?

Comment: FYI unpacking syntax doesn't work because that's `__getitem__` syntax, `[...]`, not `__call__` syntax, `(...)`.

Comment: The design of Python's type annotations is almost entirely focused around static use cases. Doing *anything* dynamically isn't well supported.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah ... `__getitem__` is a function after all, so I thought why not try. Usually, a weird thing like this just works in Python thanks to its incredible consistence.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yep, this is what "the manual" also says. In contrast, one can work with them at runtime, which is why Typeguard exists. Any idea how to make this one work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can kind of do it:

```
my_union = typing.Union[datatypes]
```

At runtime, `thing[x, y]` is already equivalent to `thing[(x, y)]`.

That said, there are limitations to keep in mind. Particularly, when using string annotations, `my_union` will have to be available in `some_function`'s global namespace for `typeguard` or anything else to be able to resolve the annotation at runtime. That restricts a lot of closure use cases, and a lot of attempts to add annotations dynamically. (String annotations may become the default eventually, but the devs are considering other options, and the plans are currently unclear.)

Also, as you might expect, mypy will not consider any of this valid.

Comment: Huh, the documentation for the `__future__` library should be updated. It still says `annotations` becomes mandatory in version 4. I'm not sure when PEP 563 was updated to say Python 3.10 (or has it always said Python 3.10?)

Comment: @chepner: I'm pretty sure PEP 563 used to say 4.0. Discussion on the [tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue38605) looks like they're making an effort to get it in by 3.10.

Answer (score 6):

I am generating OpenAPI spec automatically using pydantic.

```py
import typing

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def get_subclasses(cls):
        return tuple(cls.__subclasses__())


class Child1(Parent):
    pass


class Child2(Parent):
    pass


datatypes = typing.Union[Parent.get_subclasses()]
```

It works only because `get_subclasses` returns a tuple. I'm posting this answer because `__subclasses__` call returns a list and I was scratching my head for a moment because I couldn't understand why @user2357112 solution is not working in my case. Actually, it did, but I didn't notice they used a tuple.

Otherwise, you will run into

```
TypeError: Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type. Got [<class '__main__.Child1'>, <class '__main__.Child2'>].
```