# Registering discriminated union automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Using pydantic 1.10.7 and python 3.11.2

I have a recursive Pydantic model and I would like to deserialize each types properly using [discriminated union](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions).

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Base(BaseModel):
    kind: str
    sub_models: Annotated[
        List[Union[A,B]], 
        Field(
            default_factory=list,
            discriminator="kind"
        )
    ]

class A(Base):
    kind: Literal["a"]
    a_field: str

class B(Base):
    kind: Literal["b"]
    b_field: str
```

I would like to automatically register the subclasses in a way Pydantic will be able to understand, like so

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

B = TypeVar("B", bound="Base")

class Base(BaseModel):
    kind: str
    sub_models: Annotated[
        List[B], 
        Field(
            default_factory=list,
            discriminator="kind"
        )
    ]
    _subs: Set[Type[B]] = set()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs):
        Base._subs.add(cls)
        cls.__annotations__["kind"] = Literal[cls.__name__.lower()]  # <- works
        # list comprehension in a type definition is not valid,
        Base.__annotations__["sub_models"] = List[Union[subclass for subclass in Base._subs]]

class A(Base):
    a_field: str

class B(Base):
    b_field: str
```

Any idea how to have discriminated union configured dynamically?

I have tried registering manually the subclasses, but it involves a circular dependency of type hints and I need to "not forget" to add each new type to the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge here is that a lot of the heavy lifting of Pydantic model creation is done by the **metaclass**, specifically its [`__new__`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/main.py#L123) method.

Simply re-defining `sub_models` and `kind` in the `__annotations__` dictionary will not be enough for those changes to affect the actual **fields** because those are created and configured by the metaclass *before* `__init_subclass__` is called.

So if we don't want to go through the trouble of overriding the metaclass, we need some function to set a field on an existing (i.e. fully defined) model.

---

### Solution

This seems to work:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Annotated, Any, ClassVar, Literal, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.fields import ModelField, Undefined


def set_field_on_model(
    model: type[BaseModel],
    name: str,
    annotation: Any,
    value: Any = Undefined,
) -> None:
    """
    Inspired heavily by what is done inside `ModelMetaclass.__new__`.
    May be incomplete!
    """
    model.__fields__[name] = ModelField.infer(
        name=name,
        value=value,
        annotation=annotation,
        class_validators=None,
        config=model.__config__,
    )
    model.__annotations__[name] = annotation

# more code below...
```

Now we can use that function *inside* our `__init_subclass__` method to dynamically update the model fields we want:

```py
class Base(BaseModel):
    _subs: ClassVar[set[type["Base"]]] = set()
    sub_models: list["Base"] = Field(default_factory=list)
    kind: str

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        Base._subs.add(cls)
        set_field_on_model(cls, "kind", Literal[cls.__name__.lower()])
        if len(Base._subs) < 2:
            return  # discriminated union requires at least two distinct types
        sub_models_annotation = list[  # type: ignore[index, misc, valid-type]
            Annotated[
                Union[tuple(Base._subs)],
                Field(discriminator="kind"),
            ]
        ]
        for model in {Base} | Base._subs:
            set_field_on_model(
                model,
                "sub_models",
                sub_models_annotation,
                Field(default_factory=list),
            )
```

---

### Notes

- To "dynamically" define a type `Union`, you can just pass a tuple of types to it because at runtime `Union[X, Y]` will be equivalent to `Union[(X, Y)]`. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920231/19770795))
- For a proper definition of your `sub_models` list, you have to define the discriminated union *inside* it, i.e. you must pass the `Annotated` type as the type argument to `list` like `list[Annotated[Union[...], Field(...)]]`. The `discriminated` parameter relates to the **item type** of the list, not the list itself.
- Conversely, you must set the `default_factory` on the `sub_models` list field itself, not in the `Annotated` union of types inside the list. That is why I pass a separate `FieldInfo` as the `value` argument to `set_field_on_model` for the `sub_models` field.
- It is not enough to just modify the fields of the `Base` model during subclassing. To make everything consistent, we must also update the `__fields__` for **every subclass** of `Base`, when we create a new one. That is why I loop over `Base._subs` (and `Base` itself).
- Since a discriminated union **requires at least two types** to work, we need an escape hatch for when we subclass `Base` for the first time. If we didn't check, whether the number of sub-models is at least 2, we would get an error from Pydantic during our first subclass creation.
- This implementation for setting/overriding model fields is based on my moderate but limited understanding of the intricacies of the Pydantic machinery. It may well be that this is incomplete and there are additional steps you would have to take, to ensure everything remains consistent.
- In general, when you start fiddling with `__fields__` after the model is created, all bets are off. Meaning this is not really documented there are no guarantees that things will not break with the next release. (Not to mention Pydantic v2.)

---

### Demo/Test

Let's define (at least) two sub-models and try this out:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError

# ... import Base


class A(Base):
    a_field: str


class B(Base):
    b_field: str


test_data = {
    "kind": "a",
    "a_field": "foo",
    "sub_models": [
        {"kind": "a", "a_field": "bar"},
        {"kind": "b", "b_field": "baz"},
    ],
}
obj = A.parse_obj(test_data)
print(type(obj.sub_models[0]), type(obj.sub_models[1]))
print(obj.json(indent=4))

# Now introduce an error:
test_data["sub_models"][1]["kind"] = "a"
try:
    A.parse_obj(test_data)
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.A'> <class '__main__.B'>
```

```json
{
    "sub_models": [
        {
            "sub_models": [],
            "kind": "a",
            "a_field": "bar"
        },
        {
            "sub_models": [],
            "kind": "b",
            "b_field": "baz"
        }
    ],
    "kind": "a",
    "a_field": "foo"
}
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "sub_models",
            1,
            "A",
            "a_field"
        ],
        "msg": "field required",
        "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
]
```

That is the output we want. The two objects in the outer `sub_models` list are actually instances of distinct classes/models `A` and `B`. Their fields are all correctly assigned. And if the `kind` does not match the expected fields (as in the last example), we get a validation error.

Comment: Not only did you answer my question, but I learned quite a few things here.  Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think this is valid way to do. It used a lot of unexposed non-api parts. So it never going to be stable. And the pydantic v2 killed it already

Comment: @Wang Correct. Which is why I explicitly stated that in my original answer: _"this is not really documented there are no guarantees that things will not break with the next release"_ But when dealing with a very specific/niche problem, where there obviously is no documented way to do it and no hint that it will be officially supported in the future, using undocumented methods may be your only option. But by all means, if you have a better/stable solution for this problem, post your own answer. I would be very interested.

Comment: @Wang As for Pydantic v2 breaking this, that is not really surprising, is it? That is just how major releases work. They are **by definition** not fully backwards compatible. I am sure a lot of the existing solutions for Pydantic v1 problems on this platform will break with v2. But I would say it is silly to claim that v2 "killed" all of those solutions. Many users of Pydantic will likely keep using v1 for a long time, at least while it is still receiving updates, and not migrate to v2 immediately. But I'll take another look and maybe I'll add a v2-compatible solution later.

Comment: I am curious how to accomplish this in v2...

Comment: @JosephGarvin So far I was unable to replicate this for v2. Model construction has changed dramatically and `pydantic_core` is used for schema generation. I tried tapping into the `pydantic._internal` package, but so far unsuccessful. Maybe someone else can figure it out.